# After changing cookie path, customers where unable to login in account and checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9, cookie

I've just changed cookie path settings in magento admin. After this, on storefront, I'm unable to login as customer or on checkout page (on checkout page it redirects to empty cart). However if I open another browser everything works fine as it creates new cookie.
if I change the cookie path to previous, it works fine.
I want that, on cookie path change, it immediately reflect on storefront as we have to change the cookie path on live environment and those issues are not good for customer/visitor to face. 
Is there any solution?

Comment: Did you clean all cookies, caches from your browser?

Comment: its impractical to ask visitors to go into browser settings and manually delete website related cookies. most of em don't know it and won't understand hence not that user friendly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to reduce cookies lifetime. then you have little impact on each customer. And after some days make changes in cookies path So customer old cookies will expire asap after changes. Just make sure frontend cookies are not duplicating by doing this.

Comment: It was a very annoying thing but this solution worked like a charm.

Comment: applying this solution works perfectly. existing cookie expire time was updated and was able to change cookie settings without any customer facing logout or unable to place order.

Comment: Update: This solution worked for some but for some it didn't. I think its browser dependency or magento bug.